# Adding service reference for Silverlight Application with WCF services

Tags: silverlight, wcf

Im totally new to WCF. Trying to create a Silverlight application with WCF services.

Im not sure what address to fill in for adding the service reference for the client side.

Also, what do I need to specify in the Web config file in the server side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different kinds of WCF Services.  WCF Services, WCF Data Services & WCF RIA Services.  For a bit of background on these types/kinds check out [this forum entry](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b068efaf-4398-4d44-a907-db4531a0d731/).

If you are using just WCF Services, here's [an intro](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article816-understanding-the-basics-of-wcf-service-.aspx) [and a sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) [and another sample](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2011/01/wcf-services-with-net-4-0/) that should get you going. :-)

[Here's a great overview from Shawn Wildermuth on creating a WCF Data service & consuming it in various ways.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ee720180)

WCF RIA Services are specifically built/optimized for Silverlight.  If you are in control of the Service as well you might want to look into creating a RIA Service instead of just a WCF Data Service.   Here's an [intro to RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/).